# Axiomatization of Natural Numbers that leads to a unique model

Tags: set-theory

I'm looking for an axiomatization of the natural numbers similar to ZFC or the standard axiomatization of set theory in the language of the first order predicate calculus such that the axiomatization only has one unique model of countable cardinality. I want one that excludes the nonstandard models of the natural numbers. Can anyone cite a reference?

Comment: That's impossible! By the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem every theory that has an infinite model, has models in all infinite cardinalities. So in particular it has two non-isomorphic models.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the question to ask about countable models only. Also, does Lowenheim Skolem apply to higher order languages as well?

Comment: It doesn't. For example, second order arithmetic has only one model (up to isomorphism).